# Need assistance with Limiting Bandwidth, please

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, bandwidth

**Hello**

I have this server from online*net (Dedibox XC SATA 2016    Intel C2750 2.40GHz 16 GB   1 x 1 TB    2,5 Gbit/s). I need to lower bandwidth to 1000mbps.
I'm trying to do it via wondershaper....But i'm not too sure what my upload and download should be so I dont run into issues.

Documentation: https://documentation.online.net/en/dedicated-server/tutorials/network/configure-wondershaper

How do i find what my limit is via commandline and please help with below.

(UBUNTU 14.04 LTS 64GB SERVER)

wondershaper -a eth0 -d ?? -u ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the site you linked they give an example for 300Mb/s

> This means, if we want to shape the available bandwidth on our servers
>   network card eth0 to 300 Mbit/s both in upload and download, we launch
>   the application with the following command:

```
wondershaper -a eth0 -d 300000 -u 300000
```

So by this logic you'd need

```
wondershaper -a eth0 -d 1000000 -u 1000000
```